# SQL Server timing out during reorganize index and update stats

Tags: sql-server, timeout

When running Reorganize Index and Update Statistics in MS SQL Server 2005's maintenance plan, our production web server is timing out. I know that Reorganize Index is an online operation and that is why we chose it over Rebuild Index so we're at a loss.  It's run after a Database backup, in the same maintenance plan, but I've read that it shouldn't make a significant impact. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enterprise version? Online operation is only available in the enterprise version.

Joakim Backman

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? The MSDN page says that reorg index is  always online - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When the web server times out, is it just a plain too much load for how much capacity you have available? What does perfmon show for the avg seconds reads/writes for the physical disk? It may be as simple as throwing money at your disk subsystem.

You may want to try this instead of the reorg:

1. create a new index with a different name that is identical to existing index
2. drop existing index after new index creation is done
3. if you use query hints that specify the index name, you will have to rename the new index to match the old index name

Answer (score 0):

If you are running enterprise edition you can also rebuild the indexes online with the hint ONLINE = ON:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON table REBUILD WITH(ONLINE = ON)
```